# execute command in nebula studio to create vertex item in database

Tags: nebula-graph, nebula-studio

as mentioned in nebula documentation here :

https://docs.nebula-graph.io/1.2.0/manual-EN/2.query-language/1.data-types/data-types/

[image: nebula documentation create vertex datetime timestamp record in graph database]

nebula> INSERT VERTEX school(name, create_time) VALUES hash("new"):("new", "1985-10-01 08:00:00")

error is:

> -1005:Storage Error: The data type does not meet the requirements. Use the correct type of data.

and this:

> -1005:Wrong vertex id type: hash("new")

Comment: Dear @saber I noticed you are referring to the v1.x documentation, please always access the doc from https://docs.nebula-graph.io/ which will navigate you the latest stable version of documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be noted you are referring to NebulaGraph v1.x documentation, in NebulaGraph V1, the vid only supports int64, but now, it supports(since 2.x) string format. And you could define this during the creation of the graph space:

```sql
CREATE SPACE [IF NOT EXISTS] <graph_space_name> (
    [partition_num = <partition_number>,]
    [replica_factor = <replica_number>,]
    vid_type = {FIXED_STRING(<N>) | INT[64]}
    )
    [COMMENT = '<comment>'];
```

for instance if you created space like this:

```
CREATE SPACE IF NOT EXISTS my_space_2 (partition_num=15, replica_factor=1, vid_type=FIXED_STRING(30));
```

The vid of `"new"` is valid and no hash is needed.

ref:

- https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/3.ngql-guide/9.space-statements/1.create-space/
- https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/3.ngql-guide/12.vertex-statements/1.insert-vertex/

Answer (score 0):

for your first error please use  1669817257 this format or now() "1985-10-01 08:00:00")

like this:
[image]

```
match (v:school) return v,now() limit 10;
```

as you mentioned:
[image: nebula documentaion]

this documentation said:

> The underlying storage data type is: int64

as you can see in this picture you can define two types of spaces there:

[image: define space nebula graph]

via this form you can create/define new space:

[image: define create new space in nebula graph]

when your id is not int64 your error is the second error message that you reported

when your storage vid is int64 you should use hash